# Show or hide table row if user clicks on it (HTML/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im having a problem showing or hiding a table rows with jquery.
I want that if user clicks on table row with `id="jobtitle"` then tr with `class="texter"` will show up or hide if already opened.

my code right now is:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($works as $w){ ?>
            <tr id="jobtitle" onclick="onPress()">
                <td>
                    <?php echo $w->title; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="texter" style="display:none;">
                <td>
                    <?php echo $w->text; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    function onPress(){
            var isHidden = $('.texter').is(":hidden");
            if (isHidden == true) {
                $(".texter").show();
                $("#colorized").css("background", "#06499d");
            } else {
                $('.texter').hide();
                $("#colorized").css("background", "#20669d");
            }
    }
</script>
```

So far all tr with `class="texter"` will expand. How to make that only one tr will toggle based on click on tr with `class="jobtitle"`.

Comment: Well, first of all this expression is worded badly `isVisible = $('.texter').is(":hidden");` .... you're saying "It's Visible if it's hidden".

Comment: i have updated a expression

Comment: keep in mind, if you are going to have multiple job titles in the table, you can not use the same id `jobtitle` for all. IDs are unique in html.

Comment: You need to get some basics down. You are looping and applying the same ID (`#jobtitle`) to each element, that is a big nono in JS and CSS land.  Also you're using tables, which is an even bigger nono. I can't help you any further because the direction you're going is wrong. If you haven't already, read up on DIVs, CSS, and proper JS.

Comment: I know i'm not doing something right, so that's way im asking you guys, how to the right way. As far as i can see with this code is, that each #jobtitle has it's own function, which is clearly not a right thing to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't got 50 rep I need to write an answer instead of a comment. It somehow evolved into a complete answer rather than just a comment.

First of all, I agree that using multiple IDs inside a single HTML document is wrong and also not allowed. He fixed that, which is nice. But I also think that using tables is NOT a big "nono" as someone called it above. *Not always*, at least.
Using a table as a table and not for layouting, is imo totally legit. But the OP just builds a single column table, where you actually wouldn't need a table. In this case, a better practice would be using `<div>` elements and remove inline CSS as followed:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <?php $num = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($works as $w){ ?>
        <div id="colorized<?php echo $num; ?>" class="fromage">
            <div class="title">
                <?php echo $w->title; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="texter">
                <?php echo $w->text; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $num++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Then, I'd use the jQuery-method `toggleClass()`. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.title').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("baguette");
    });
});
```

An let the CSS do the magic:

```
.texter {
    display: none;
}

.fromage {
    background: #06499d;
    cursor: pointer; /* to show it's clickable */
    padding: .5em; /* pure beauty */
    color: #fff; /* pure beauty */
}

.baguette .texter {
    display: block;
}

.baguette.fromage {
    background: #20669d;
}
```

Voilá!

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10vm4c9n/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do? If you click on `id='jobtitle'`, the child with `class='texter'` will get shown.

```
$('#jobtitle').on('click', function(){
   $(this).find('.texter').show(); 
});
```

Or if `id='jobtitle'` has `class='texter'`, show texter

```
$('#jobtitle').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass.('texter')){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, this is it what i'm i trying to do , but that code doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you can put it in a JSfiddle then we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It's not really nice but it works for now, until i will refactor whole code.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <?php $num = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($works as $w){ ?>
          <tr id="colorized<?php echo $num; ?>" onclick="onPress(<?php echo $num; ?>)">
                <td>
                    <?php echo $w->title; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="texter<?php echo $num; ?>" style="display:none;">
                <td>
                    <?php echo $w->text; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
          <?php $num++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And JavaScript

```
function onPress(value){
        var isHidden = $('.texter'+value).is(":hidden");
        var id = "texter"+value;
    $(".texter"+value).fadeToggle();
        if (isHidden == true) {
            $(".id").show();
            $("#colorized"+value).css("background", "#06499d");
        } else {
            $(".id").hide();
            $("#colorized"+value).css("background", "#20669d");
        }
}
```